# MySQL solution for multiple column totals

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am retrieving multiple records from a table in MySQL. Is there a way that I can retrieve one row which totals each of the columns from this query? I was hoping that there might be an SQL solution, as I'll be repeating the process for many tables as it's being used for a dynamic report.

If there is no SQL solution, is there a way to easily add together all the nested arrays inside of an array? This would achieve the same result, but in PHP.

I can't seem to find any information on either approach.

Comment: Please add an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using using aggregation.  You don't give much guidance on what your query looks like, but something like:

```
select sum(col1) as sumcol1, sum(col2) as sumcol2, . . . 
from t;
```

Without the `group by` clause, this returns one row, which is a summary of everything in t.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you exactly want to achieve by reading your question as you did not provide any codes or data. Try the following:

```
SELECT id, col_1, col_2, col_3, col_4, sum(t.Col)
FROM
(SELECT id, col_1, col_2, col_3, col_4, 
SUM(col_1+col_2+col_3+col_4)
AS Col
FROM datas
WHERE id = '1'
GROUP BY id)t
```

You can see the fiddle [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/56f00/3)